# Can I run laravel 4 and 5 at the same time?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.4

We have a Knowledge management system which built in Laravel 4 running in school server. It was first launched last year 2016, and now we've created a separate app built in Laravel 5.4. **The server in our school is unable to upgrade its PHP drivers since it has softwares running in lower version of PHP**, only our app can run with the latest php drivers. How can we launch our app in our school server?

Comment: How is your server power? Do you know Docker?

Comment: Try for [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead)

Comment: PHP >= 5.6.4 see Server Requirements: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation

Comment: Thank you @JaredChu! However, I cannot +1 your answers since my reputation is too low. Anyhow, thanks you so much for your answer/recommendation!

Comment: And thank you @user2486 also!